Manipulating Hail Matrix Table
I have a hail matrix table, and when i run mt_filtered.describe(), i get the following:
----------------------------------------
Global fields:
    None
----------------------------------------
Column fields:
    's': str
    'metadata': struct {
        ``: int32, 
        gender_concept_id: int32, 
        gender: str, 
        date_of_birth: str, 
        race_concept_id: int32, 
        race: str, 
        ethnicity_concept_id: int32, 
        ethnicity: str, 
        sex_at_birth_concept_id: int32, 
        sex_at_birth: str, 
        survey_datetime: str, 
        survey: str, 
        question_concept_id: int32, 
        question: str, 
        answer_concept_id: int32, 
        answer: str, 
        survey_version_concept_id: str, 
        survey_version_name: str
    }
----------------------------------------
Row fields:
    'locus': locus<GRCh38>
    'alleles': array<str>
    'filters': set<str>
    'a_index': int32
    'was_split': bool
    'variant_qc': struct {
        gq_stats: struct {
            mean: float64, 
            stdev: float64, 
            min: float64, 
            max: float64
        }, 
        call_rate: float64, 
        n_called: int64, 
        n_not_called: int64, 
        n_filtered: int64, 
        n_het: int64, 
        n_non_ref: int64, 
        het_freq_hwe: float64, 
        p_value_hwe: float64, 
        p_value_excess_het: float64
    }
    'info': struct {
        AC: array<int32>, 
        AF: array<float64>, 
        AN: int32, 
        homozygote_count: array<int32>
    }
    'annotations': struct {
        vid: str, 
        transcript: str, 
        contig: str, 
        position: int32, 
        ref_allele: str, 
        alt_allele: str, 
        gvs_all_ac: str, 
        gvs_all_an: str, 
        gvs_all_af: str, 
        gvs_all_sc: str, 
        gvs_max_af: str, 
        gvs_max_ac: str, 
        gvs_max_an: str, 
        gvs_max_sc: str, 
        gvs_max_subpop: str, 
        gvs_afr_ac: str, 
        gvs_afr_an: str, 
        gvs_afr_af: str, 
        gvs_afr_sc: str, 
        gvs_amr_ac: str, 
        gvs_amr_an: str, 
        gvs_amr_af: str, 
        gvs_amr_sc: str, 
        gvs_eas_ac: str, 
        gvs_eas_an: str, 
        gvs_eas_af: str, 
        gvs_eas_sc: str, 
        gvs_eur_ac: str, 
        gvs_eur_an: str, 
        gvs_eur_af: str, 
        gvs_eur_sc: str, 
        gvs_mid_ac: str, 
        gvs_mid_an: str, 
        gvs_mid_af: str, 
        gvs_mid_sc: str, 
        gvs_oth_ac: str, 
        gvs_oth_an: str, 
        gvs_oth_af: str, 
        gvs_oth_sc: str, 
        gvs_sas_ac: str, 
        gvs_sas_an: str, 
        gvs_sas_af: str, 
        gvs_sas_sc: str, 
        gene_symbol: str, 
        transcript_source: str, 
        aa_change: str, 
        consequence: str, 
        dna_change_in_transcript: str, 
        variant_type: str, 
        exon_number: str, 
        intron_number: str, 
        genomic_location: str, 
        dbsnp_rsid: str, 
        gene_id: str, 
        gene_omim_id: str, 
        is_canonical_transcript: str, 
        gnomad_all_af: str, 
        gnomad_all_ac: str, 
        gnomad_all_an: str, 
        gnomad_failed_filter: str, 
        gnomad_max_af: str, 
        gnomad_max_ac: str, 
        gnomad_max_an: str, 
        gnomad_max_subpop: str, 
        gnomad_afr_ac: str, 
        gnomad_afr_an: str, 
        gnomad_afr_af: str, 
        gnomad_amr_ac: str, 
        gnomad_amr_an: str, 
        gnomad_amr_af: str, 
        gnomad_asj_ac: str, 
        gnomad_asj_an: str, 
        gnomad_asj_af: str, 
        gnomad_eas_ac: str, 
        gnomad_eas_an: str, 
        gnomad_eas_af: str, 
        gnomad_fin_ac: str, 
        gnomad_fin_an: str, 
        gnomad_fin_af: str, 
        gnomad_nfr_ac: str, 
        gnomad_nfr_an: str, 
        gnomad_nfr_af: str, 
        gnomad_sas_ac: str, 
        gnomad_sas_an: str, 
        gnomad_sas_af: str, 
        gnomad_oth_ac: str, 
        gnomad_oth_an: str, 
        gnomad_oth_af: str, 
        revel: str, 
        splice_ai_acceptor_gain_score: str, 
        splice_ai_acceptor_gain_distance: str, 
        splice_ai_acceptor_loss_score: str, 
        splice_ai_acceptor_loss_distance: str, 
        splice_ai_donor_gain_score: str, 
        splice_ai_donor_gain_distance: str, 
        splice_ai_donor_loss_score: str, 
        splice_ai_donor_loss_distance: str, 
        omim_phenotypes_id: str, 
        omim_phenotypes_name: str, 
        clinvar_classification: str, 
        clinvar_last_updated: str, 
        clinvar_phenotype: str
    }
----------------------------------------
Entry fields:
    'GT': call
    'GQ': int32
    'RGQ': int32
    'FT': str
    'AD': array<int32>
----------------------------------------
Column key: ['s']
Row key: ['locus', 'alleles']
----------------------------------------

I want to create a barplot such that the x-axis is the different genes (mt_filtered.annotations.gene_symbol), and there will be pairs of bars for each gene. One bar in each pair will represent the count of male samples and the other bar will be the count of female samples. The gender is given in mt_filtered.metadata.gender.
I tried the following code, but i got some errors:
# Aggregate the counts of male and female for each gene
gender_counts = mt_filtered.group_rows_by(
    mt_filtered.annotations.gene_symbol
).aggregate(
    male_count=hl.agg.count_where(mt_filtered.metadata.gender == 'Male'),
    female_count=hl.agg.count_where(mt_filtered.metadata.gender == 'Female')
)

# Convert to Pandas DataFrame for plotting
gender_df = gender_counts.rows().to_pandas()

# Reshape the DataFrame for seaborn plotting
gender_df = gender_df.melt(id_vars=["gene_symbol"], value_vars=["male_count", "female_count"], 
                           var_name="gender", value_name="count")

# Replace 'male_count' and 'female_count' with 'Male' and 'Female' for better plot labels
gender_df['gender'] = gender_df['gender'].replace({'male_count': 'Male', 'female_count': 'Female'})

# Plot the results
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 6))
sns.barplot(data=gender_df, x='gene_symbol', y='count', hue='gender')
plt.xlabel('Gene')
plt.ylabel('Count')
plt.title('Count of Male and Female Samples for Each Gene')
plt.legend(title='Gender')
plt.show()

Here is the error message:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[35], line 13
     10 gender_df = gender_counts.rows().to_pandas()
     12 # Reshape the DataFrame for seaborn plotting
---> 13 gender_df = gender_df.melt(id_vars=["gene_symbol"], value_vars=["male_count", "female_count"], 
     14                            var_name="gender", value_name="count")
     16 # Replace 'male_count' and 'female_count' with 'Male' and 'Female' for better plot labels
     17 gender_df['gender'] = gender_df['gender'].replace({'male_count': 'Male', 'female_count': 'Female'})

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py:8975, in DataFrame.melt(self, id_vars, value_vars, var_name, value_name, col_level, ignore_index)
   8965 @Appender(_shared_docs["melt"] % {"caller": "df.melt(", "other": "melt"})
   8966 def melt(
   8967     self,
   (...)
   8973     ignore_index: bool = True,
   8974 ) -> DataFrame:
-> 8975     return melt(
   8976         self,
   8977         id_vars=id_vars,
   8978         value_vars=value_vars,
   8979         var_name=var_name,
   8980         value_name=value_name,
   8981         col_level=col_level,
   8982         ignore_index=ignore_index,
   8983     ).__finalize__(self, method="melt")

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/melt.py:92, in melt(frame, id_vars, value_vars, var_name, value_name, col_level, ignore_index)
     90     missing = Index(com.flatten(value_vars)).difference(cols)
     91     if not missing.empty:
---> 92         raise KeyError(
     93             "The following 'value_vars' are not present in "
     94             f"the DataFrame: {list(missing)}"
     95         )
     96 if col_level is not None:
     97     idx = frame.columns.get_level_values(col_level).get_indexer(
     98         id_vars + value_vars
     99     )

KeyError: "The following 'value_vars' are not present in the DataFrame: ['female_count', 'male_count']"

I will greatly appreciate any suggestion on how I can get the desired plot. Thanks

gender_df = pd.melt(gender_df, id_vars=["gene_symbol"], value_vars=["male_count", "female_count"], var_name="gender", value_name="count"). pd.melt not gender_df.melt.
